# How do I alter ListView data within a Custom List Adapter?

Tags: android, button, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener, listadapter

I'm trying to make a ListView of a grocery list in which clicking on any of the buttons alters the quantity of the particular item.  This is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="$14.99" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lessButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="lessButton"
        android:text="-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantityText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/moreButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="moreButton"
        android:text="+" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTotalText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="$0.00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Java code for the Custom Adapter, heavily influenced by TheNewBoston's video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOdSARCVYic):

```
public class ListCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

public String description = "";
public double price = 0;
public Integer quantity = 0;


public ListCustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String[] items) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_list_row, items);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, parent, false);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");

    String entry = getItem(position);
    TextView descriptionText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
    TextView priceText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
    TextView quantityText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.quantityText);
    Button lessButton = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.lessButton);
    Button moreButton = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);

    final Integer ENTRIES = 100;
    String c = "";
    String tempString = "";
    Integer field = 0;
    //Decoding the data.
    System.out.println("String entry at position "+ position+ ": "+ entry);
    for (int a = 0; a <= entry.length()-1; a++)
    {
        c = entry.substring(a,a+1);
        System.out.println("Character line "+a+" : "+ c);
        if (!c.equals("*"))
        {
            tempString += c;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Tempstring: "+tempString);
            if (field == 0)
            {
                description = tempString;
            }
            else if (field == 1)
            {
                price = Float.valueOf(tempString);
            }
            else if (field == 2)
            {
                quantity = Integer.valueOf(tempString);
            }
            field++;
            tempString = "";
            if (field > 2)
            {
                field = 0;
            }

        }
    }


    descriptionText.setText(description);
    priceText.setText("$"+df.format(price));
    quantityText.setText(quantity.toString());

    lessButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (quantity > 0)
            {
                quantity--;
            }


        }
    });

    moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (quantity < ENTRIES)
            {
                quantity++;
            }


        }
    });



    return customView;
}




}
```

An explanation for the "Decoding the data" section:  Each String item is just one giant string that contains the description, price, and quantity like so "Beef*3.33*0*".  There's probably a better way to do it, but that's all I know right now.

Anyway, on the button OnClickListeners, what do I need to do to make sure the quantity of that particular item is altered, and reflected in the ListView?  I've heard of notifyDataSetChanged(), but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: In this case, you can just setText in quantityText, after you change the quantity

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just setText in quantityText, after you change the quantity.

```
lessButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (quantity > 0)
        {
            quantity--;
            //put this value in quantityText
            quantityText.setText(quantity.toString());
        }


    }
});

moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (quantity < ENTRIES)
        {
            quantity++;
            //put this value in quantityText
            quantityText.setText(quantity.toString());
        }


    }
});
```

But then you'll have to change the "one giant string" to have the new quantity, (for some possible cases where you need to use that 'one giant string' with the new values)

A better approach would be to make a class GroceryProduct with the required fields and make objects. (In case you are familiar with OOP). In this case notifyDataSetChanged() would be particularly helpful.

Comment: OK; I still need to learn how to make that class, but for the time being, once I have that "one giant string", how do I let the CustomAdapter know of the new value?  In other words, how would I alter the "getItem(position)" which contains that string?